# SUM values of CASE in Mysql GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I am not sure this is possible but below is what I am trying to achieve.

```
$sql = "SELECT CASE WHEN products.type=1 THEN 50 WHEN products.type=2 THEN 25 ELSE 0 END 'PROD_NUM', CASE WHEN categories.id=4 THEN 12 WHEN categories.id=7 THEN 40 ELSE 5 END 'CAT_NUM', ('PROD_NUM'+'CAT_NUM') 'TOTAL_NUM' FROM products JOIN categories..... GROUP BY products.color....
```

This is of course just a mock example but the question is it possible to sum the values of the two CASE? Thanks

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the aggregation (and it seems from the OP you don't), you can actually use the names of the 'computed columns' in SELECT expression:

```
SELECT 
  CASE products.type
    WHEN 1 THEN 50 
    WHEN 2 THEN 25 
    ELSE 0 END `PROD_NUM`, 
  CASE categories.id
    WHEN 4 THEN 12 
    WHEN 7 THEN 40 
    ELSE 5 END `CAT_NUM`, 
  (SELECT PROD_NUM) + (SELECT CAT_NUM) `TOTAL_NUM` 
FROM products
```

[Here's the sample DBFiddle (works on MySQL 5.7).](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8N5wmp4CZXbE9hN6QxTDCS/0) This approach won't handle the columns computed with aggregate functions though.

Comment: I tested this and it actually works for my needs. I did not know about that feature, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    p.color,
    SUM(CASE p.type WHEN 1 THEN 50 WHEN 2 THEN 25 ELSE 0 END) AS PROD_NUM,
    SUM(CASE c.id WHEN 4 THEN 12 WHEN 7 THEN 40 ELSE 5 END) AS CAT_NUM
    SUM(CASE p.type WHEN 1 THEN 50 WHEN 2 THEN 25 ELSE 0 END) +
      SUM(CASE c.id WHEN 4 THEN 12 WHEN 7 THEN 40 ELSE 5 END) AS TOTAL_NUM
FROM products p
INNER JOIN categories c
-- ON etc.
GROUP BY p.color;
```

Note that you'll have to repeat both `CASE` expressions if you want to sum them together.  The only way around this would be to subquery your current query, and then add the `PROD_NUM` and `CAT_NUM` aliases.  But, given that the `CASE` expressions are fairly small, I vote for the above version.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was afraid of, having to run the CASE twice since at least one has a subquery that is a part of the calculation. I may resort to doing the calculation in PHP instead, should be faster at least for one of the SUM. Thank you again.

Comment: No...don't do the math in PHP if you can avoid that.  Just subquery my answer and then sum the `CASE` expressions.

Comment: Good point, I will give that a try and compare the execution time. Thanks.